# Why can't you reduce the visibility of a method in a Java subclass?

Tags: java, polymorphism, overriding, subclassing

Why does the compiler give an error message when you reduce the visibility of a method while overriding it in the subclass?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Because every instance of the subclass still needs to be a valid instance of the base class (see [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)).

If the subclass suddenly has lost one property of the base class (namely a public method for example) then it would no longer be a valid substitute for the base class.

Comment: But why are we not allowed to override a protected method and change it to private? Since the public interface is still the same, it doesn't break LSP this way.

Comment: The public interface does not change, but the protected does. Code in the parent class cannot access the methods of its own flesh and blood :(

Answer (score 19):

Because if this was allowed, the following situation would be possible:

Class Sub inherits from class Parent. Parent has a public method `foo`, Sub makes that method private. Now the following code would compile fine, because the declared type of `bar` is Parent:

```
Parent bar = new Sub();
bar.foo();
```

However it is not clear how this should behave. One possibility would be to let it cause a runtime error. Another would be to simply allow it, which would make it possible to call a private method from outside, by just casting to the parent class. Neither of those alternatives are acceptable, so it is not allowed.

Comment: C++ solves this problem by controlling the visibility of the inheritance relation.

Also strange in Java is that super class constructors can call (virtual) subclass methods, i.e. in a scope, where the subclass instance is in an undefined state.

Answer (score 1):

Because subtypes have to be usable as instances of their supertype.