# Inheritance and public/private methods

Tags: java

**One.java**

```
public class One {

    private void run() {
        System.out.println("one");
    }

    public void start() {
        this.run();
    }
}
```

**Two.java**

```
public class Two extends One {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("two");
    }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Two t = new Two();
        t.start();
    }
}
```

Output: one

But if I declare the `run` method `public` in the `One` class I get "two" as output.

It is pretty unpredictable, how does this work?

Comment: When `One`s `run` method is private, `Two` can't access it. When it's `public` the version in `Two` overrides it.

Comment: @JonK you cannot override a private method

Comment: @ControlAltDel I didn't say you could.

Comment: @JonK that's how I read your comment. But you've got a lot of up votes so maybe that's just me :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `run` method in `Two` will not be overriding the `private` method in `One`, because it is `private` and inaccessible to any class outside `One`.

Once the method is marked as `public`, the inheritance system takes place, and `run` is invoked from `start` in `One` (as the method is not overridden), but then resolved dynamically (at runtime) as `Two`'s `run`.

My advice, use the `@Override` annotation to make sure at compile-time that a method is properly overridden.

Also, you seem to be playing with `start` and `run` methods: remember you need to `extend Thread` or `implement Runnable` for the JVM to recognize your classes as `Runnable`s.

Comment: but why in private case `this.run()`  give output One's method rather than Two's run because `this` in the `Two` object not `One`

Comment: @codegasmer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5378995/confused-with-java-overriding-the-access-level

Answer (score 1):

In Java, `private` methods are **NOT** visible to subclasses. `Protected` methods **ARE**.

In the class `Two` you did *not* override the `start()` method, therefore `t.start()` uses `One.start()` which calls `One.run()` which prints "one".

If you change the `run()` method to `public` or `protected` the `Two` class will override it and calling `t.start()` will end up calling the version declared in `Two`.

In "flowchart" form:
When `run` is `private`

> Two.start() -> not defined! -> go to superclass -> One.start() -> run() -> One.run()

When `run` is `public` or `protected`

> Two.start() -> not defined! -> go to superclass -> One.start() -> run() -> run() is overridden by subclass -> go to subclass -> Two.run()

Answer (score 0):

Because run is private in One, it is not dynamically linked, nor inherited. The run in Two does NOT override the run in One