# how to prevent client to access public function of base class

Tags: java

```
//cls_a is defined by system framework, so we cannot change its definition
public class cls_a {
  public void method_a();
}

//I add a new cls_b implemenation and would like to 
//add a new method_a(int) function
//and prevent client side to access cls_a.method_a()
public class cls_b extends cls_a {
  public void method_a(int a) {
    //do something for a
    method_a();
  }
}

//client side
cls_b b = new cls_b();
b.method_a(2); //it's okay
b.method_a(); //should give something error when compiling code
```

I would like to design `cls_b` so that the Java compiler will give an error when client side calls `b.method_a()`. Anyone knows how to do it in Java?

Comment: @rai.skumar what part of the comment *cls_a is defined by system framework, so we cannot change its definition* didn't you understand?

Comment: my bad..indeed i din't notice :(

Answer (score 3):

What I do now is adding a @Deprecated annotation to method_a() (see below example), so client side will get a warning. Since the warning is easy to be ignored, are there any way to make compiler giving an error?

`public class cls_b extends cls_a {
  //add @Deprecated 
  @Deprecated @Override public void method_a() {
    super.method_a();
  }
  public void method_a(int a) {
    //do something for a
    method_a();
  }
}`

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that because you cannot reduce the visibility of an inherited method (e.g. if it is public, you cannot make it private).

[Why can't you reduce the visibility of a method in a Java subclass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600667/why-cant-you-reduce-the-visibility-of-a-method-in-a-java-subclass) explains why that is.

Answer (score 2):

Once you make it public, then its scope is available over the project. There is no way to make a public function hidden from a specific class

Update: I just read your question again. I think you want other developers when calling the method_a() from b will get the exception. If it is what you want, then you can try

```
package com.test;


public class ClassA {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        ClassB b = new ClassB();
        b.print();
    }
}

class ClassC {
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("printA");
    }
}

class ClassB extends ClassC {

    public void print() {
        try {
            throw new Exception("This method is dead");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void print(int i) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution is a kind of runtime checking. I prefer to get a static checking solution (find the error at compiling stage).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way: Expose a wrapper class for clients.

```
 public class cls_a_Wrapper {
      private cls_a a;

      cls_a_Wrapper(){
          a = new cls_a();
      }  

      //methods
      public void method_a_wrapper(){
           a.method_a();
      }
  }

 public class cls_b extends cls_a_Wrapper {
      public void method_a_wrapper(int a) {

           //delegate to wrapper class method if its allowed
           method_a_wrapper();
     }
  }
```

So now your client should user class **cls_a_Wrapper** class instead of **cls_a**.

So now you can control if you want to call base class's public method. This is **Adapter Design patter**.

**If you don't want to call a public method :**

- don't provide method in your wrapper class.
- **OR** change visibility of method in your wrapper class

**Remember** : For client original class doesn't exist. Client should treat wrapper class as the base class.

Comment: There are lots of functions defined in cls_a. 
It will be a burden to use wrapper class solution.

Comment: You can directly delegate to cls_a class methods as done in method_a_wrapper(). So methods will be very lightweight unless you want to put any check. But this approach is better in terms of design.

Comment: have improved it bit more..hope it makes sense :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reduce a method's visibility in a subclass.

JDK solves similar problems with UnsupportedOperationException, e.g.

```
java.util.Arrays.UnmodifiableCollection

    ...
            public boolean add(E e) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }
    ...
```

java.util.Collection API marks this kind of methods as `optional operation`

```
boolean add(E e) Ensures that this collection contains the specified element (optional operation).
```

Comment: This solution is also a kind of runtime checking. I don't like it as the error can only be caught by test cases. I prefer to have a static checking solution (find the error at compiling stage).

Comment: Right, I think JDK developers would also prefer to remove add(E e) from UnmodifiableCollection but this is impossible in OOP.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent client from accessing public function of base class is not a good choice. Even you can give a runtime exception or deprecated method, clients also could call your method by `cls_a` type.

```
cls_a a = new cls_b();
//...
a.method_a();
```

The better way is to give a **default implementation** of `method_a`. For your code,

```
public class cls_b extends cls_a {
  public void method_a() {
    this.method_a(0);
  }

  public void method_a(int a) {
    //do something for a
    super.method_a();
  }  
}
```