# There was protected in a file created automatically what was private

Tags: android, eclipse

When I make a new Android Application Project 
I see the automatic generate `MainActivity.java` file.

Why was the "`OnCreate`" protected

I remember this was private. I don't understand. why made this?

For example this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: it was never private, it needs to be overridden by the sub-classes

Answer (score 2):

It never was `private`, if it was private then how you were able to `Override` it?? You might have seen it `public` because subclass can not reduce the visibility of a method. Read this question for clarification. [Why can't you reduce the visibility of a method in a Java subclass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600667/why-cant-you-reduce-the-visibility-of-a-method-in-a-java-subclass)