# since all interface method are public, does that mean all implementation of interface method must be public as well

Tags: java, interface, public

since all interface method are public, does that mean all implementation of interface method must be public as well? I have read that subclass can only assign 
access level that is higher than the original method. I have tried this with some code and it does seem to be true, but I was just wondering where can I find documentation regarding to this?

Comment: Yes, that's true. Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36422728/276052) from earlier this week.

Comment: You seem to have all you need. Note: in Java 9, private methods on interfaces will be allowed.

Comment: I think OP is asking for the *documentation*.

Comment: @TonyStark can you change the title of your question to highlight that you are looking for the _documentation_, not an _explanation_? Some people seem not to be reading the actual question.

Comment: @PeterLawrey do you please tell me how you got to know that java 9 will allow private on interface? is there an website where I can find the latest news regarding to java?

Comment: @TonyStark take a look at http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdk9-dev/2015-March/001981.html and http://aruld.info/private-interface-methods-in-java-9/ regarding private methods in Java 9

Comment: Looks like no one cares that this question is off-topic, since it requests off-site resources ...

Comment: @Tom You are right. Note to self: Don't post when tired! Flagged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the official documentation of that requirement in the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html).

Quoting from [8.4.8.3. Requirements in Overriding and Hiding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3):

> The access modifier (§6.6) of an overriding or hiding method must provide at least as much access as the overridden or hidden method, as follows:
>
> **If the overridden or hidden method is public, then the overriding or hiding method must be public; otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.**
>
> If the overridden or hidden method is protected, then the overriding or hiding method must be protected or public; otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.
>
> If the overridden or hidden method has package access, then the overriding or hiding method must not be private; otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.

Answer (score 3):

As in the official Java Tutorial by Oracle:

> interfaces are a kind of contract all implementing classes have to stick to

This means, the signature of a method, the return type and the access modifier are **not** allowed to be changed.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/index.html

Also if you try to tag an interface-method with the `@Override` annotation, the compiler will throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

`Interface`s are created to be an **interface** for using classes that implement them.

For example we implement a `Comparable` interface to be trusted that the class has `compareTo` method which can be **used** by other classes.

So it's not possible and I don't see a point in doing that.

I didn't found a part of documentation which exactly refers to your question but it can be understood from this part:

> If the overridden or hidden method is public, then the overriding or hiding method must be public; otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.