# How to protect a method implementing an interface from overriding?

Tags: java, visibility

I have interface:

```
public interface Doable {
    void doSomething();
}
```

and the class that implements it:

```
public class DoJump() implements Doable {
    @Override
    private void doSomething() {
        fireJumpHandler();
    }
}
```

This is stupid example, but I would like to present the problem.

This code doesn't compile, I am getting an error in Eclipse IDE:

> Cannot reduce the visibility of the inherited method from
>   Doable

I have common interface that declares a method. This method is overriden in concrete class. I would like to avoid another class that can extend this class (`DoJump`), so I would like to hide this method from sub classes. I would like to use `private` modifier, but Java does not allow me to do it.

Why it is impossible, and how to workaround it?

Comment: You're looking for `final`, not `private`.

Comment: See also: [java access modifiers and overriding methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851612/java-access-modifiers-and-overriding-methods)

Comment: You cannot make the method hidden, as it is defined in the Interface as public. If you want to hide it, encapsulate the functionality in a new private method and call new method from the ``doSomething`` method.

Comment: See also: [Why can't you reduce the visibility of a method in a Java subclass?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600667/why-cant-you-reduce-the-visibility-of-a-method-in-a-java-subclass)

Comment: Hint: you also want to read about the Liskov substituation principle. Basically your idea of **reducing** an interface simply leads to designs that are not sound any more in OO design.

Comment: I'd like to answer your last question `"How to workaround it?"` as this is not described in the related question. Create a second interface `NotDoable` which simply does not have `doSomething()` declared. Then let your `DoJump` implement both interfaces. Give everyone that shouldn't override `doSomething` a reference to the interface `NotDoable` instead of the true type `DoJump`. Then they won't know that the object truly can `doSomething`, they won't know per class design. Of course, one can workaround this but one actually can workaround everything. The class design is more correct this way.

Comment: I edited a question to make it about work-around, not about the reason why this is happening. This differs sufficiently from the duplicate, good enough to be reopened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd like to answer your last question `"How to workaround it?"` as this is not described in the related question. Create a second interface `NotDoable` which simply does not have `doSomething()` declared. Then let your `DoJump` implement both interfaces. Give everyone that shouldn't override `doSomething` a reference to the interface `NotDoable` instead of the true type `DoJump`. Then they won't know that the object truly can `doSomething`, they won't know per class design. Of course, one can workaround this but one actually can workaround everything. The class design is more correct this way. Here's some code:

```
public interface Doable {
    public void doSomething();
}

public interface NotDoable {

}

public class DoJump implements Doable, NotDoable {
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("hi");
    }

    public NotDoable meAsNotDoable() {
        return this;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DoJump object = new DoJump();

        // This call is possible, no errors
        object.doSomething();

        NotDoable hidden = object.meAsNotDoable();

        // Not possible, compile error, the true type is hidden!
        hidden.doSomething();
    }
}
```

But as said, one can workaround this by using `if (hidden instanceof DoJump) { DoJump trueObject = (DoJump) hidden; }`. But well, one can also access private values via reflection.

Other classes now implement `NotDoable` instead of extending `DoJump`. If you declare everything others should know about `DoJump` in this interface, then they only can do what they should do. You may call this interface `IDoJump` and the implementing class `DoJump`, a common pattern.

Now the same a bit more concrete.

```
public interface IDog {
    public void bark();
}

public interface ICanFly {
    public void fly();
}

public class FlyingDog implements IDog, ICanFly {
    @Override
    public void bark() {
        System.out.println("wuff");
    }

    @Override
    public void fly() {
        System.out.println("Whuiiii");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FlyingDog flyingDog = new FlyingDog();

        // Both works
        flyingDog.fly();
        flyingDog.bark();

        IDog dog = (IDog) flyingDog;

        // Same object but does not work, compile error
        dog.fly();

        ICanFly canFly = (ICanFly) flyingDog;

        // Same object but does not work, compile error
        canFly.bark();
    }
}
```

And now an *extending* class.

```
public class LoudDog implements IDog {
    @Override
    public void bark() {
        System.out.println("WUUUUFF");
    }

    // Does not work, compile error as IDog does not declare this method
    @Override
    public void fly() {
        System.out.println("I wanna fly :(");
    }
}
```

In the end, be aware that if others know that their `IDog` actually is a `FlyingDog` (and they cast it), then they **must** be able to call `fly()` as a `FlyingDog` must can fly. Furthermore, they **must** be able to override the behavior as long as they follow the specification of `fly()` given by its `method-signature`. Imagine a `subclass` called `PoorFlyingDog`, he needs to override the default behavior, else he can perfectly fly, but he is a poor flyer.

Summarized: Hide to others that you're actually a `DoJump`, also hide that you are a `Doable`, pretend to only be a `NotDoable`. Or with the animals, pretend to only be an `IDog` instead of a `FlyingDog` or `ICanFly`. If the others don't *cheat* (casting), they won't be able to use `fly()` on you, though you actually can fly.

Answer (score 2):

Add `final` to `DoJump` declaration to prevent this class to be overriden (and therefore `doSomething()` to be overriden too).

```
public final class DoJump implements Doable {
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        fireJumpHandler();
    }
}
```

If you still need to be able to inherit `DoJump` but you don't want `doSomething()` to be overriden, put the `final` modifier in the method signature

```
public class DoJump implements Doable {
    @Override
    public final void doSomething() {
        fireJumpHandler();
    }
}
```

Comment: Good spot at the second option! I think that is exactly what *op* wanted.